# Primeng disabled button changes color when hovered

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I have changed p-button styles on hover .

My problem is when the button state is set to disabled and I hover it the color changes also.

```
<button pButton type="submit" label="Launch @RT" class="ui-button-success color" [disabled]="groupList.length+ejList.length>0 ? false: true"></button>
```

Then in CSS:

```
.ui-button-success.ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget:hover:disabled, .ui-button-success.color{
    background-color: white !important;
    color: #00965E;
}
.ui-button.ui-button-success:hover
{
    background-color: #00965E !important;
    color: white;
}
```

How can I unchange button style when it's disable and I hover it. but when it's enable change color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `:not()` selector here with `:hover`

```css
.ui-button-success {
  background-color: white;
  color: #00965E;
}

.ui-button-success:not([disabled]):hover {
  background-color: #00965E;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="ui-button-success color" disabled>foobar</button>
<button type="button" class="ui-button-success color">foobar</button>
```